# Erro em função remover c++

Tags: c++

Boa noite pessoal,
Não estou conseguindo fazer a função remover funcionar. Encontra o número mas não exclui o valor do vetor.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 100

typedef struct {
    int numero;
    char nome[20];
} VENDEDOR;

typedef struct {
    VENDEDOR vetor[MAX];
    int numElementos;
} LISTA;

void criar(LISTA *lista);
int vazia(LISTA lista);
int cheia(LISTA lista);
bool inserir(LISTA *lista, VENDEDOR v1, int);
void remover(LISTA lista, int numero, int pos);
void buscaNome(LISTA lista, char nome[], int pos);
void buscaNumero(LISTA lista, int numero, int pos);
void imprimir(LISTA lista);

int main() {
    LISTA lista;
    VENDEDOR v1;
    int pos = 1;
    int numero;
    char nome[20];

    int op;
    do {
        cout << "Digite a opção desejada:" << endl;
        cout << "1- Criar" << endl;
        cout << "2- Vazia" << endl;
        cout << "3- Cheia" << endl;
        cout << "4- Inserir" << endl;
        cout << "5- Remover" << endl;
        cout << "6- Buscar nome" << endl;
        cout << "7- Buscar número" << endl;
        cout << "8- Imprimir" << endl;
        cout << "0- Sair" << endl;
        cout << "Opção:";
        cin>>op;

        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                criar(&lista);
                break;
            case 2:
                vazia(lista);
                break;
            case 3:
                cheia(lista);
                break;
            case 4:
                inserir(&lista, v1, pos);
                break;
            case 5:
                remover(lista, numero, pos);
                break;
            case 6:
                buscaNome(lista, nome, pos);
                break;
            case 7:
                buscaNumero(lista, numero, pos);
                break;
            case 8:
                imprimir(lista);
                break;
        }
    } while (op != 0);
    return 0;
}

void criar(LISTA *lista) {
    lista->numElementos = 0;
    cout << "Lista criada" << endl << endl;
}

int vazia(LISTA lista) {
    if (lista.numElementos == 0) {
        cout << "Lista vazia" << endl << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Lista com elementos" << endl << endl;
    }
}

int cheia(LISTA lista) {
    if (lista.numElementos == MAX) {
        cout << "Lista cheia" << endl << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Lista com espaço" << endl << endl;
    }
}

bool inserir(LISTA *lista, VENDEDOR v1, int pos) {
    cout << "Número: ";
    cin >> v1.numero;
    cout << "Nome: ";
    cin >> v1.nome;
    int i;
    if (lista->numElementos == MAX || pos > lista->numElementos + 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (i = lista->numElementos; i > lista->numElementos; i--) {
        lista->vetor[i] = lista->vetor[i - 1];
    }
    lista->vetor[i] = v1;
    lista->numElementos++;
    cout << endl;
    return true;
}

void remover(LISTA lista, int numero, int pos) {
    cout << "Digite o número para apagar: ";
    cin>>numero;
    int i;
    bool aux = true;
    for (i = 0; i <= pos; i++) {
        if (numero == lista.vetor[i].numero) {
            lista.vetor[i].numero = lista.vetor[i + 1].numero;
            cout << "Removido com sucesso!" << endl;
            aux = false;
        }
    }
    pos--;
    if (aux) {
        cout << "Não encontrado!" << endl;
    }
}

void buscaNome(LISTA lista, char nome[], int pos) {
    cout << "Digite o nome para pesquisar: ";
    cin>>nome;
    int i;
    bool aux = true;
    for (i = 0; i <= pos; i++) {
        if (nome[pos] == lista.vetor[i].nome[pos]) {
            cout << "Número: " << lista.vetor[i].numero << endl << endl;
            aux = false;
        }
    }
    if (aux) {
        cout << "Não encontrado!" << endl;
    }
}

void buscaNumero(LISTA lista, int numero, int pos) {
    cout << "Digite o número para pesquisar: ";
    cin>>numero;
    int i;
    bool aux = true;
    for (i = 0; i <= pos; i++) {
        if (numero == lista.vetor[i].numero) {
            cout << "Nome: " << lista.vetor[i].nome << endl << endl;
            aux = false;
        }
    }
    if (aux) {
        cout << "Não encontrado!" << endl;
    }
}

void imprimir(LISTA lista) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.numElementos; i++) {
        cout << "Número: " << lista.vetor[i].numero << endl;
        cout << "Nome: " << lista.vetor[i].nome << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma pequena observação, é que seus métodos tem parâmetros, mas ainda assim, são lidos valores dentro deles.

Não é correto usar variáveis de parâmetros para armazenar valore (exceto se for retornar valores por ponteiros).

```
// Acho q se já tem uma posição para remover o valor, não
// há necessidade de passar o número a ser removido também

#define MAX_LEN 10

void remover(Lista lst, int pos){
    // Mostra erro se posição for inválida ou de não ouver valor na lista
    if(pos < 0 || pos >= MAX_LEN || !lst.vetor[x].numero){
        cout << "Não foi possível remover o valor dessa posição." << endl;
        return; // encerra método sem retorno
    }

    for(int x=pos; x<MAX_LEN-1; x++){
        // Passa todos os valores apos a posição a ser removida
        // para a posição anterior da lista
        lst.vetor[x].numero = lst.vetor[x+1].numero;
    }
    //limpa o ultimo valor (caso [tenho|não tenha] valor).
    lst.vetor[MAX_LEN-1].numero = 0;
}
```

Comment: Não consegui fazer seu código funcionar. Entendo o que falou sobre valores dentro dos métodos, mas dentro da função que fiz ele encontra o número a ser excluído mas não exclui. Onde que está o erro na minha função?